# How to avoid ubuntu 20.04 got suspended

Tags: suspend

I have a rig with ubuntu 20.04, when I unplugged the monitor goes to suspended status (but still running the appa. I have some questions about:

1. How can I unsuspend with the keyboard (my keyboard doesn't have the power button, so there are any keyboard combination to resume the suspend status?
2. How avoid the rig got suspended?

Comment: Are you talking about Ubuntu Server? or Ubuntu Desktop?

Comment: Ubuntu desktop, I have to plug the monitor to every card to see what does wake up, it is very rare, because the same operanting system was installed in the other rig and doesn't have this problem. But it has another hardware

Comment: What do you mean by 'appa'?

Comment: Still running the apps. Sorry for the misstype